# python dictionary(dictionary(dictionary(list))) comparison

Tags: python, list, dictionary, comparison

so I want a way to compare d1 and d2

```
d1=
{"tables":
  {"k1":
    {"columns":
      ["val1","val2","val3"]
    },
    "forward":
    {"k2":
      ["val1","val2","val3"]
    }
  }
}

d2= 
{"tables":
  {"k1":
    {"columns":
      ["val2","val1","val3"]
    },
    "forward":
    {"k2":
      ["val2","val1","val3"]
    }
  }
}
```

and come up equal. These two dictionaries of lists come from different sources and I want the least verbose solution. I am sure it is trivial but I'm quite stuck right now.

EDIT1:
so apparently you understood my question. That is exactly what I mean. The lists are not equal and I don't know beforehand they are lists or how many dictionaries are there before there is a key set corresponding to a list. These come from a json string so the dictionaries don't discriminate between a list and a set (I guess...)

Comment: Have you considered `d1 == d2`?

Comment: What constitutes equality here of the two data structures?

Comment: These are not equal. The lists are not in the same order.

Comment: That's precisely what I mean. ``[1, 2, 3]`` != ``[3, 2, 1]]``

Comment: It would probably be easier using sets.

Comment: That's probably the easiest way you can make the above expression ``True`` :) i.e:  ``set([1, 2, 3]) == set([3, 2, 1]])``

Comment: How much of the structure can you rely on being the same? Will it always be a dictionary of dictionaries of dictionaries of lists? Do you care about the order of any of the lists? What is *your definition* of equality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about the order of *any* `list` within your dictionary structure, you can recursively convert them all to the unordered `set` data structure:

```
def lists_to_sets(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, list):
            d[k] = set(v)
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            lists_to_sets(v)
```

This assumes that the lists contain hashable objects - if they contain e.g. `dict`s this will not work. In action:

```
>>> d1 = {"tables": {"k1": {"columns": ["val1", "val2", "val3"]},
                     "forward": {"k2": ["val1", "val2", "val3"]}}}
>>> d2 = {"tables": {"k1": {"columns": ["val2", "val1", "val3"]},
                     "forward": {"k2": ["val2", "val1", "val3"]}}}
>>> d1 == d2
False
>>> lists_to_sets(d1)
>>> lists_to_sets(d2)
>>> d1 == d2
True
```